# Can we develop in a Pycharm interface in our computer while running it with the computational resources and environment in another remote PC

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, remote-access, remote-debugging

Can we develop in a Pycharm interface in our computer while using the computational resources and environment in another remote PC?

For example in Jupyter Notebook, we can execute the following command inside the remote PC:

jupyter notebook --ip 135.2.55.205 --port 8888

Which allows us to access the notebook with that ip-address remotely from any other computer and after doing so, the codes we we write remotely in the notebook would use the CPU or GPU of the that remote PC. So when I use the debugging feature of PyCharm or simply run the code, I would like the computation to be carried out in the remote PC similar to using the above Jupyter Notebook with that ip address.

Can we do the same with PyCharm? I know in PyCharm we can for example define a remote virtual-environment, but I guess that would still use our own computational power rather than a remote machine.

A similar approach would probably be if I just do remote-desktop to the remote PC, but that won't be very convenient.

Comment: Have you looked at doing this with `ssh`/SFTP? Here's how to confiture editing in PyCharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Also, Visual Studio Code is another editor/IDE that does a nice job of remote editing and terminal running over ssh:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host

Finally, running jupyter lab instead of jupyter notebook will give you a shell on that remote machine and the ability to edit files:
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @hume Does ssh/SFTP allow both the computation and the interpreter to be from the remote machine? At the moment I get "cannot connect to X server" when I use it :/  JupyterLab is also good but doesn't have the functionalities of the PyCharm debugger

Comment: @AMC I'm still doing, but I don't know which is the best practical way. What is important for me is that I use the computational power of the remote machine.

Comment: @Azerila You can configure PyCharm to run a "remote interpreter" over ssh (sftp) as well, so using that interpreter for execution or debugging will should make that possible. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#

I have also used the VSCode version which you only have to configure once to be "remote" and then the terminal within VScode, any execution, and the editing all happen on the remote server.

Comment: @hume worked:) although since my code also would have brought a dynamic GUI, it was rather slow through X11 forwarding. Nevertheless, I would choose your answer as correct.

Comment: Great! Cleaned up this thread and added the answer. Let me know if anything should be added to make it more clear based on your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in PyCharm by configuring file editing and execution remotely over SSH (SFTP for the files, which uses SSH). The first step will allow you to see and edit files on the other (remote) machine. The second step will allow you to run a Python interpreter (and therefore debugging) on that same remote machine.

Here is how to configure editing your code on the remote machine using PyCharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Here is how to configure a remote Python interpreter that will run on the remote machine:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#

For completeness, two other options outside of PyCharm are to (1) use VS Code and the ["remote host" functionality](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host). And (2) run jupyter lab on the remote machine which will give you a file editor and terminal on that machine in addition to notebooks.